# Spivak, Ch. 25, Problem 8b

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

The following problem is from Chapter 25, "Complex Numbers", from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 8. (a) Let $c$ be an integer which is not the square of another integer. If $a$ and $b$ are integers we define the conjugate of
>    $a+b\sqrt{c}$, denoted by $\overline{a+b\sqrt{c}}$ as $a-b\sqrt{c}$.
>    Show that the conjugate is well defined by showing that a number can
>    be written $a+b\sqrt{c}$, for integers $a$ and $b$, in only one way.
>
> (b) Show that for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of the form $a+b\sqrt{c}$,
> we have  $\overline{\alpha^{-1}}=(\overline{\alpha})^{-1}$, if
> $\alpha\neq 0$.

The proof of part (a) is

> Let $n$ be a number. Suppose we can write $n$ as $a+b\sqrt{c}$ and
> $a'+b'\sqrt{c}$.
>
> **Case 1:** $b=b'$. Then, $a=a'$.
>
> **Case 2:** $b\neq b'$. Then, $\sqrt{c}=-\frac{a-a'}{b-b'}$, a rational number.
>
> But, in a previous problem (Chapter 2, problem 17) it was proved that
> for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational unless $n=m^2$ for
> some $m\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Thus, case 2 is not possible, since by assumption $c$ is not a perfect
> square.
>
> Therefore, there is only one way to write $n$ as $a+b\sqrt{c}$.

**My question is about item (b).**

Item (b) actually asks us to prove six things (things like $\overline{\alpha+\beta}=\overline{\alpha}+\overline{\beta}$, or $-\overline{\alpha}=\overline{-\alpha}$), and above I only wrote the one I am stuck on, which is the last thing.

Here is my attempt at solving this

If $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{c}$ then $\alpha^{-1}$ is defined by $\alpha\cdot\alpha^{-1}=1$, so

$$\alpha^{-1}=\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{c}}=\frac{a-b\sqrt{c}}{a^2-b^2c}$$

At this point it is not clear how to proceed.

$\frac{a}{a^2-b^2c}$ and $\frac{-b}{a^2-b^2c}$ are not necessarily integers, so that it is not clear to me how to obtain $\overline{\alpha^{-1}}$.

Note that $\overline{\alpha}=a-b\sqrt{c}$ and

$$\overline{\alpha}\cdot\overline{\alpha}^{-1}\implies \overline{\alpha}^{-1}=\frac{a+b\sqrt{c}}{a^2-b^2\sqrt{c}}$$

Comment: If I trust your report, Spivak simply forgot to extend his definition of the conjugate to elements of the form $a+b\sqrt c$ with $a,b$ *rational*.

Comment: That's what I think happened yes. But for the way the problem is actually stated, there isn't any way to proceed, right?

Comment: Right. Btw I wonder why the downvote. Whence my upvote.

Comment: @AnneBauval this is the third downvote on a question about complex numbers this week. Looks like someone following this tag has beef with me.

Comment: In my edition, this is Chapter 24, not 25.